# aptly can't open database leveldb

Tags: apt, leveldb

Probably after a reboot, the MANIFEST file have been cleared and is now empty

```
:# aptly repo show -with-packages unstable
ERROR: can't open database: leveldb: manifest corrupted (field 'comparer'): missing [file=MANIFEST-010975]
```

I'm looking for a way to rebuild the MANIFEST,
or to backup the db, reinstall it properly and restore my backup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "aptly db recover"? http://www.aptly.info/doc/aptly/db/recover/

Comment: Yes I did, it went through without error but it didn't restore MANIFEST file